# Angular migration issue from 2.1.1 to 4.0.0

Tags: angular

I am trying to migrate the application from Angular2.0 to Angular4.0, but I am getting around 2500 errors when I try to compile the application after npm updates. 
My package.json file is as follows

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.6",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.6.3",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "systemjs": "0.20.12",
    "zone.js": "0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.4.0",
    "lite-server": "2.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.2",
    "typings": "2.1.1"
  }
```

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/app/"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "Scripts"
  ]
}
```

Some of the errors which I am getting:-

```
1>C:\...\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_for_of.d.ts(18,14): error TS1005: Build:'=' expected.
1>C:\...\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_for_of.d.ts(18,19): error TS1005: Build:';' expected.
1>C:\...\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_for_of.d.ts(19,14): error TS1005: Build:'=' expected.
1>C:\...\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_for_of.d.ts(19,18): error TS1005: Build:';' expected.
...
1>C:\...\node_modules\@angular\common\src\location\platform_location.d.ts(39,22): error TS1005: Build:';' expected.
1>C:\...\node_modules\@angular\common\src\location\platform_location.d.ts(40,14): error TS1005: Build:'=' expected.
..
1>C:\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\jit\compiler.d.ts(39,22): error TS1005: Build:';' expected.
1>C:\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\output\abstract_emitter.d.ts(23,22): error TS1005: Build:'=' expected.
1>C:\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\output\abstract_emitter.d.ts(27,9): error TS1110: Build:Type expected.
```

any ideas why I am getting this many errors during migration?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: @DeborahK, I have just taken a look at the link given by you, I am working on AspNet core application with Angular2.   After updating my package.json and after the restore packages, during compilation I am getting the above mentioned errors.